# User slicer to filter on another value

Tags: powerbi

I'm wanting to filter a table, let's call it "Capitals," indirectly based on a slicer value.  Here's an example looking at capital cities:

| Current_Name | Prior_Name | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abuja | Abuja | 12/12/1991 | 12/31/9999 |
| Abuja | Lagos | 1/1/1914 | 12/11/1991 |
| Nur-Sultan | Nur-Sultan | 3/23/2019 | 12/31/9999 |
| Nur-Sultan | Astana | 12/1/1997 | 3/22/2019 |
| Nur-Sultan | Almaty | 1/1/1991 | 11/30/1997 |
| Brasilia | Brasilia | 4/21/1960 | 12/31/9999 |
| Brasilia | Rio de Janeiro | 1/1/1900 | 4/20/1960 |

My slicer shows all prior names (assume no duplicates).  If I select Astana, for example, I want to see the list of ALL prior names that share the current name: Nur-Saltan, Astana, Almaty.  I feel like I would want `FILTER(Capital, Capital[Current_Name] = SELECTEDVALUE(Capital[Current_Name])`, but then I'm not sure how to show the list of prior names.  Thanks.

Comment: what is the logic that give Nur-Saltan, Astana, Almaty

Comment: they share the same current name